# How do you find the next element with a specific attribute, then get that element's attribute value?

Tags: html, jquery

Let's say I click on an element. I'm trying to get the next element with the attribute "for", then return its content (so for="Content I want").

I don't know in advance what the type of element with that attribute will be. Sometimes it's an input, sometimes a label, etc.

In my example, it's a label, but it could be an input. The clicked element would be the div.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div class="styled-placeholder quarter InputText" data-test="">
  <label class="input-label" for="Year">Year</label>
  <input id="Year" type="number" name="Year" class="input-control required" placeholder="Year" required="" minlength="0" maxlength="4" value="">
  <p class="errors-input">Type Your Birth Year</p>
</div>
```

This is what I have now:

```
function() {
var attr = jQuery({{Click Element}}).next('[for]').attr('for');

return attr;
}
```

Comment: Show a representative sample of your html, and specify what attribute you’re selecting for/with, and what exactly should happen; what events should cause what action(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you are looking for the **next** element. Based on your HTML that you have provided, there is no next element. So the element with the `for` attribute is a **child** element.

This is how you could get the first child element with attribute `for`:

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
  const el = $(this).children('[for]')[0];
  console.log('Attribute value: ' + $(el).attr('for'));
  console.log('Content: ' + $(el).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-placeholder quarter InputText" data-test="">
  <label class="input-label" for="Year">The Year</label>
  <input id="Year" type="number" name="Year" class="input-control required" placeholder="Year" required="" minlength="0" maxlength="4" value="">
  <p class="errors-input">Type Your Birth Year</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute Equals Selector with jQuery

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```js
$("[value='Test value']").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).nextAll("label[for]:first").attr('for'));
});

$("[data-test]").click(function() {
   //console.log($(this).data('test')); 
   console.log($(this).nextAll("label[for]:first").attr('for'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Test value"><br>
<label for="test1">Test Data</label>
<button data-test="test">test data</button>
<label for="test2">Test Data</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  My only issue is that I'm also trying to find the content of this attribute afterwards, so specifying its value as a filter to find the next element is not possible as I dont know it in advance. 

For example, I'm trying to find the next element with the attribute "for" (i.e for="..."), then return the content of the attribute "for".

Comment: @JosianneTl i edited my answer, plz check it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple javascript, no library needed:

`document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="value"]');`

```js
let element = document.querySelectorAll('[foo="value"]');
console.log(element[0]);
```

```html
<button foo="value">Submit</button>
```